# Sorting data based on specified value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, t-sql

I have a table `Containers` with following data:

```
Name         | CapacityNormal | CapacityMax
-------------+----------------+------------
Container #1 |              2 |           2
Container #2 |              2 |           3
Container #3 |              2 |           4
Container #4 |              3 |           4
Container #5 |              3 |           5
```

And a variable `Quantity`. I want to sort containers with respect to quantity in this order:

- containers whose capacity normal is greater than/equal to quantity
- containers whose capacity max is greater than/equal to quantity
- everything else

Note that:

- Wasting normal slots is not desireable
- Exceeding normal capacity incurs a pealty

Keeping the above in mind the ties must be broken according to these rules:

- containers with smallest *wasted* normal capacity
- containers with smallest *penalty*

If Quantity = 3 the expected output would be:

```
Name         | CapacityNormal | CapacityMax | Comment
-------------+----------------+-------------+-------------------------------------------
Container #4 |              3 |           4 | wastes 0 slots
Container #5 |              3 |           5 | wastes 1 slot
Container #2 |              2 |           3 | exceeds normal capacity, incurs 1 penalty
Container #3 |              2 |           4 | exceeds normal capacity, incurs 2 penalty
Container #1 |              2 |           2 | container cannot be used
```

Put another way, I want to choose best container for the job that does not exceed normal capacity or incurs smallest penalty. Here is sample data and test:

```sql
WITH Containers(Name, CapacityNormal, CapacityMax) AS (
    SELECT 'Container #1', 2, 2 UNION
    SELECT 'Container #2', 2, 3 UNION
    SELECT 'Container #3', 2, 4 UNION
    SELECT 'Container #4', 3, 4 UNION
    SELECT 'Container #5', 3, 5
), Tests(Quantity) AS (
    SELECT 1 UNION 
    SELECT 2 UNION 
    SELECT 3 UNION 
    SELECT 4 UNION 
    SELECT 5 UNION
    SELECT 6
)
SELECT CONCAT(Name, ' (', CapacityNormal, '/', CapacityMax, ')') AS Container, Quantity
FROM Containers
CROSS JOIN Tests
ORDER BY Quantity /* sort criteria goes here */
```

Comment: I have revised the requirements a little, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use order by like this

```
;WITH Containers(Name, CapacityNormal, CapacityMax) AS (
   SELECT 'Container #1', 2, 2 UNION
   SELECT 'Container #2', 2, 3 UNION
   SELECT 'Container #3', 2, 4 UNION
   SELECT 'Container #4', 3, 4 UNION
   SELECT 'Container #5', 3, 5 UNION 
   SELECT 'Container #6', 4, 5
), Tests(Quantity) AS (
   SELECT 1 UNION 
   SELECT 2 UNION 
   SELECT 3 UNION 
   SELECT 4 UNION 
   SELECT 5 UNION
   SELECT 6
)
SELECT *
FROM Containers c
CROSS JOIN Tests t
ORDER BY Quantity,
       CASE WHEN c.CapacityNormal >= t.Quantity THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
       CASE WHEN c.CapacityMax >= t.Quantity THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,     
       abs(c.CapacityNormal- quantity) ,
       abs(c.CapacityMax - quantity)
```

**Note**:  Order by      `CASE WHEN c.CapacityNormal >= t.Quantity THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
       CASE WHEN c.CapacityMax >= t.Quantity THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`  is equivalent to

- containers whose capacity normal is greater than/equal to quantity
- containers whose capacity max is greater than/equal to quantity

and then order by `abs(c.CapacityNormal- quantity) ,
                   abs(c.CapacityMax - quantity)` would guarantee

- containers with smallest wasted normal capacity containers with
- smallest penalty

Comment: This breaks when I introduce a new case `Container #6 (4/5)`... it still chooses `3/5` which has penalty 2, it should have instead choose `4/5` which has 1 penalty.

Comment: What is your quantity you are testing?

Comment: that was tested against 5

Answer (score 0):

You could use an order by statement something like this:

```
order by 
    case 
        when capacitynormal >= quantity then 1
        when capacitymax >= quantity then 2
        else 3
    end,
    case 
        when capacitynormal >= quantity then capacitynormal - quantity
        else 9999 --set this to a number bigger than any capacity normal
    end,
    capacitymax - quantity
```

Note that I used a case statement for the second element, as well, because I think your question implies that if you have exceeded normal capacity you want to ignore that in the tiebreaking logic.

Comment: For Quantity = 2 it can put `Container #3 (2/4)` at the top. ideally it should return `Container #1 (2/2)`, `Container #2 (2/3)` and `Container #3 (2/4)` in that order.